# Как удалить из строки слова оканчивающиеся на определённый символ(форматирование в regex)

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, строки, форматирование

Нужно удалять из строки слова оканчивающиеся на определённый символ который мы вводим. Т.е. к примеру из текста "Иван Иванович носил кран" и ввести символ н, должно выводить "Иванович носил".

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ое_продвинутое
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine ("Введите строку из которого нужно удалить элементы которые оканчиваются на * ");
        String s = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine ("Введите букву");
        string k = Console.ReadLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ((Regex.Replace(s, @"{0,}"+k, "")).Trim());
        //нужно заменить как-то @"{0,}:"+k чтобы брало все значения оканчивающиеся на k


        Console.ReadKey ();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: если я правильно понял, то нужно перед {0,} добавить символ который может являться любой буквой

Answer (score 2):

Используйте границу слова, если под "словом" имеется в виду обычное слово натурального языка:

```
var s = "Иван Иванович носил кран";
var bukva = "н";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, $@"\s*\w*{bukva}\b", "").Trim());
// => Иванович носил
```

См. [C#-демо](https://ideone.com/pGLjXi)

**Подробности**

- `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `\w*` - 0+ букв/цифр/_
- `{bukva}` - буква (интерполированная переменная)
- `\b` - граница слова

Answer (score 0):

"[^ ]{0,}"+k+" ", расшифровка [^ ] значит любой символ кроме пробеля, {0,} что символ стоящий перед этими скобками(в данном случае любой кроме пробеля) может быть повторён много раз, +k+ значит добавить значение k, а " " в конце должен находодиться пробель(т.к. именно так он проверяет слово, поэтому при вводе строки в конец добавляем пробел)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ое_продвинутое
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine ("Введите строку из которого нужно удалить элементы которые оканчиваются на * ");
        String s = Console.ReadLine()+" ";
        Console.WriteLine ("Введите букву");
        string k = Console.ReadLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ((Regex.Replace(s, "[^ ]{0,}"+k+" ", "")).Trim());
        Console.ReadKey ();

    }
}
```

}